# Deployed Bot Framework Bot 404 error on api/messages

Tags: botframework, azure-web-app-service, azure-qna-maker

When I run a GET query on

`https://<mybot>-dev-web.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`
or 
`http://localhost:3978/api/messages`

I see:

```
{
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "/api/messages; caused by Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\src\\api\\messages'"
}
```

The bot is deployed and otherwise works correctly. In the emulator using localhost, the bot works and has conversations as expected.

When I have a conversation with the deployed bot, I can connect and the bot initiates a conversation, but errors out. The request is to directline:

`https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/L6QlXXXXXXXXXXcF4oe4-j/activities`

with payload

```
{
  "text":"start a new quote",
  "textFormat":"plain",
  "type":"message",
  "channelData":{
    "clientActivityID":"15828426409370.peq9o6sa7me"
   },
  "channelId":"webchat",
  "from":{"id":"r_zm9bajki87","role":"user"},
  "locale":"en-US",
  "timestamp":"XXXX"
}
```

response is:

```
{
  "id": "L6QlV72c1dxEdT1JcF4oe4-j|0000001"
}
```

I think my bot is maybe communicating the wrong way, but pretty much everything is default. I have tried to update the web.config file because the path to api/messages seemed incorrect but I'm not sure what it's supposed to be. Thanks!

Comment: Which document did you refer to? The bot worked fine locally, but didn't work after deploying to azure?

Comment: your bot messaging endpoint should be in the format https://<your-bot>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages. Does your bot work as expected in 'Test in Web Chat' on Azure?

Comment: It seems like the url is wrong.